# Conditional expectation problem regarding the exponential distribution

Tags: probability

> The lifetime of a machine part is exponentially distributed with a
> mean of five years. Calculate the mean lifetime of the part, given
> that is survives less than ten years

### Attempt

Let $X$ be lifetime of part. We know $f_X(x) = \frac{1}{5} e^{-\frac{x}{5}}$. We want to calculate

$$ E(X | X<10) = \int x P(X | X<10) dx$$

Now,

$$ P(X|X<10) = \frac{ P( {X} \cap \{X<10\} ) }{P(X<10)} $$

here is where I get confused as I am having trouble understanding how can we compute $P( {X} \cap \{X<10\}$)$. Is this a correct approach to solve this problem?

Comment: You can only take probabilities of events.  $X$ is a random variable, not an event, and so $P[X|X<10]$ does not make sense.  Likewise, the intersection $X \cap \{X<10\}$ does not make sense.  If you want to compute a conditional density $f_{X|A}(x)$ (where $A$ is some event), one way is to compute the conditional CDF $P[X\leq x|A]$ and take a derivative with respect to $x$.

Comment: @Michael can you say $P( {X=x}\ \cap \ \ X<10 \ )$?

Comment: Yes $P[\{X=x\} \cap \{X<10\}]$ makes sense.  We have $P[\{X=x\}\cap \{X<10\}]=P[\phi]=0$ if $x\geq 10$, and $P[\{X=x\}\cap \{X<10\}] = P[X=x]$ if $x <10$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complementary cumulative distribution $P(X > t | X < 10)$ is what you need. This is indeed preserving the relative distribution less than 10 but normalizing them by the probability that it was less than 10. $$P(\{X > t\} \cap \{X  < 10\} )/ P(X < 10 ) = P(\{t < X <10 \})/ P(X < 10 ).$$

$$ E (X | X < 10) = \int_{0}^{10} P (X > t | X < 10 ) dt$$ (This is true for positive random variables. You could also do it as  $\int t P(X = t|X < 10)dt.$)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Formula_for_non-negative_random_variables

$$ P(t < X < 10) = e^{-t/5} - e^{-10/5} = e^{-t/5} - e^{-2}.$$

$$P(\{t < X <10 \})/ P(X < 10 ) = \frac{e^{-t/5} - e^{-2}}{1 - e^{-2}}$$

$$\int_{0}^{10} P (X > t | X < 10 ) dt = \int_{0}^{10} \frac{e^{-t/5} - e^{-2}}{1 - e^{-2}}dt  = \frac{1}{1 - e^{-2}} \int_{0}^{10} e^{-t/5} - e^{-2}dt =  $$

$$\frac{1}{1 - e^{-2}} \Big[-5 e^{-t/5} - te^{-2}\Big]_{0}^{10} $$

Comment: Isn't is supposed to be $X \leq t $

Comment: @JimmySabater Yes - but I am using a simple result which helps with exponentials.